# Slime give Connection broken by remote peer when open large file with cl-json

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, slime

When using emacs+slime:

```
(cl-json:decode-json-from-source (pathname "/path/to/test.json"))
```

will give

```
Connection broken by remote peer when open large file
```

when open large file(14M)
[file link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zX2kUGMN-bEI2hsbgwlEoLy0qUbBWQEM/view?usp=sharing)

while in sbcl(terminal) it is ok.

Please tell me why is that happen and how should I handle it?

Comment: Have you tried saving the output only into a variable instead of displaying everything?  Emacs can choke on big buffers, especially if there is syntax highlighting.

Comment: yeah, I have tried something like `(setf a (cl-json:....))` but it give the same error too. Maybe it is because output to the buffer `*inferior-lisp*`? Or the return from `(setf ...)`?

Comment: `Setf` returns the last thing it sets, so that gets printed by the REPL again.  Use `defparameter`, which is cleaner than `setf`ing a place that doesn't exist anyway.